# Поиск максимального элемента при помощи Stream в Java

Tags: java, потоки-данных

Здравствуйте.
В задаче нужно найти максимальный элемент в списке.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, почему неправильно работает следующий код:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(847);
        list.add(271);
        list.add(879);
        System.out.println(maxElem(list));
    }

    public static Integer maxElem(List<Integer> list){
        Integer max = list.stream()                    
                .max(Math::max)
                .get();
        return max;
    }
}
```

В результате выводится не 879, как ожидается, а 847. Почему?

**UPD**.
В комментариях подробно объяснили, почему код работает неправильно. Повторяться не буду, приведу просто разные варианты правильного кода.

```
Integer max = list.stream().reduce(Integer::max).get();
Integer max = list.stream().reduce(Integer.MIN_VALUE, Integer::max);
Integer max = list.stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).max().getAsInt();    
Integer max = list.stream().collect(Collectors.summarizingInt(Integer::intValue)).getMax();    
Integer max = list.stream().max(Comparator.naturalOrder()).get();
Integer max = list.stream().max(Integer::compare).get();
Integer max = list.stream().max((a, b) -> {
    if (a > b) return 1;
    else if (a < b) return -1;
    else return 0;
}).get();
```

Comment: лучше использовать `max(Integer::compare)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Math::max` возвращает `(a >= b) ? a : b`, а stream.max() принимает **Comparator**, который работает по-другому: Comparator-у "нужны" три базовые значения: -1 если меньше, 0 если равны и  1 если больше, а метод Math::max не то возвращает.

поэтому, вам нужно использоват свой Comparator или использовать готовый в классе Integer: `Integer.compare`

Answer (score 5):

Метод [Stream.max](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#max-java.util.Comparator-) принимает `Comparator`. Попробуйте передать его:

```
Integer max = list.stream()                    
            .max(Comparator.naturalOrder())
            .get();
```

Сейчас Вы передаете в `max` метод `Math.max`. Java воспринимает этот метод как реализацию [Comparator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) и пытается определить максимум, используя метод `Math.max` как `Comparator.compare`. Т.к. `Math.max` не является корректной реализацией операции сравнения, возвращается непредсказуемый результат.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте, это работает у меня

```
    public static Integer maxElem(List<Integer> values){
        if (values.isEmpty()) return null;
        Integer max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        for(Integer value : values){
            if (max.compareTo(value)==-1){
                max = value;
            }
        }
        return max;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Вроде все элементарно просто:

```
Integer max = Arrays.stream(inputArray).max().getAsInt();
```